# How to convert Datetime to hexadecimal

Tags: c#

I was trying to convert the datetime to hexadecimal. 
This is what I have

```
string hexValue = DateTime.Today.ToString("X")
```

I can not find the solution to this.

Comment: How do you want your date represented as Hex? For example, what is hex for today 10th July 2017?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @Jamiec yes like that

Comment: @PedroAzevedo - yes like *what*? I asked a question, not suggested a solution!

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I wanted to register this in the windows registry

Comment: @PedroAzevedo what is the problem to register the result of `DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()`?

Comment: @Jamiec For example I wanted the date of today to be in hexadecimal to serve as the installation date but for a normal user can not understand what it is

Comment: haha, hex encoding as encryption. I love it! I hope your users are either preschoolers or you dont care that much about license fees.

Comment: @Jamiec this is for the school xD

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do:

```
string hexValue = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("X2");
```

This will give you the `hex` value.

To convert it back to `DateTime` you do:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(hexValue, 16));
```

Comment: This is probably the most sensible answer to a not-very-sensible question.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks :) This puts me very close to my first tag badge 0.0

Answer (score 1):

You can do following with C#.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.Now;
//Convert date time format 20170710041800
string str = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");           
//Convert to Long 
long decValue = Convert.ToInt64(str);
//Convert to HEX 1245D8F5F7C8
string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
//Hex To Long again 20170710041800
long decAgain = Int64.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Please mark as answer if it is helpfull to you

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string ConvertStringToHex(string asciiString)
{
    string hex = "";
    foreach (char c in asciiString)
    {
        int tmp = c;
        hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
    }
    return hex;
}
```